# How do i loop and add the items to comboBox so it will start from 1 to 8?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
for (int xx = 0; xx < piCount; xx++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(xx);
}
```

piCount is int. And the value of it is 8.
If i'm starting from 0 i will see in the comboBox 01234567
But i want to see 12345678

Answer (score 7):

Just change your loop:

```
for (int xx = 1; xx <= piCount; xx++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(xx);
}
```

Notice how the upper limit comparison is changed form `<` to `<=`.

You can also keep your loop and add 1 in the body:

```
for (int xx = 0; xx < piCount; xx++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(xx + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change counters like this

```
for (int xx = 1; xx <= piCount; xx++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(xx);
}
```

Now this starts from 1 and goes to so on upto the piCount.

Answer (score 0):

change your loop as:

```
for (int xx = 1; xx <= piCount; xx++)
```